# What is this Control or View?

Tags: android, layout, view, draggable

Please see the Image

hello I want to use this type of Layout in my application[image]

If I drag one layout to any direction then i want to display other Layout

is it possible please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

*Main.java*:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerScrollListener;

public class Main extends Activity {

    SlidingDrawer   mSlide;
    ImageView       mImageSlideHandle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSlide = ((SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.slide));
        mImageSlideHandle   = ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.handle));

        mSlide.setOnDrawerScrollListener(new OnDrawerScrollListener(){
            @Override
            public void onScrollEnded() {
                if (mSlide.isOpened()) {
                    mImageSlideHandle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tray_expand);
                } else {
                    mImageSlideHandle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tray_collapse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStarted() {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

*main.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

    <TextView  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="@string/hello" />

    <SlidingDrawer 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:handle="@+id/handle" 
         android:content="@+id/content" 
         android:id="@+id/slide" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@id/handle" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tray_expand"
            android:background="@drawable/handle" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@id/content" 
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button 
                android:text="Button01" 
                android:id="@+id/Button01" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button 
                android:text="Button02" 
                android:id="@+id/Button02" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can get all the pictures you need from this link http://www.megaupload.com/?d=K55W7P4T

Answer (score 1):

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/08/android-sliding-drawer-example.html
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-tutorial

This is android SlidingDrawer to use this follow the above link

Answer (score 1):

you can use a SlidingDrawer , 
follow this link [SlidingDrawer Tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-tutorial)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could a sliding drawer or u could use  the  [interpolator](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/) to do the same stuff